# Values of Incomplete gamma function

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Look this claim :

Does   $\Gamma(0.5,-x^2)= i\alpha$, for $x$  large real number?

i=unity imaginary part

$\alpha$ is real number

I would like someone  to prove me this if it's a true claim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maple,
$$
\Gamma(1/2,-10000)=\sqrt {\pi\ }{\rm erfc} \left( 100\,i \right) = 1.772453851-{
 8.807258633\times 10^{4340}}\,i
$$

So, in fact it is not purely imaginary.  But the imaginary part is so much larger than the real part, one can see why you might think it is.

**added**

Think of it this way:
$$
\Gamma(1/2,-x^2) = \int_{-x^2}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt
= \int_{-x^2}^0 \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt+\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt
$$
The first integral is purely imaginary, and the second integral is $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$, which is nonzero.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but i want the analytic prove not by maple or wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 0):

we assume  that :$\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}dx=\frac{(-1)^{^{-\tfrac12}}}2\cdot\Gamma\bigg(\frac12,-x^2\bigg)$,  if we accepted :

$f(x)$=$\frac{x }{2x²-1}e^{x²}$ as a good asymptotic approximation to the antiderivative of

${e^{x²}}$ for large $x$  , it's seems that the values of $f(x)$ are real for large $x $,

implies that $\Gamma(0.5,-x²) $ =$i\alpha$ for large $x $ values

,$\alpha $ is real number and $i$=unit imaginary part

Comment: No, it does not imply that $\Gamma(1/2,-x^2)$ is equal to $i\alpha$, merely that it is "close to" $i\alpha$ .... in the relative sense.  As we see from my answer, the distance to $i\alpha$ is $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: pleas see this asymptotic approximation :$f'(x)=(\frac{x}{2x^{2}-1}e^{x^{2}})'$= $\frac{4x^{4}-4x^{2}-1}{4x^{4}-4x^{2}+1}e^{x^{2}}$, we have :$\displaystyle\int e^{x^2}dx=\frac{(-1)^{^{-\tfrac12}}}2\cdot\Gamma\bigg(\frac12,-x^2\bigg)$ , where $\frac{(-1)^{^{-\tfrac12}}}2$=$+ or -i/2$ , if we accepted this approximation, your basic yield to be false , thanks